# trying to open flake8 on vs code from command palette error on mac

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8

I've installed flake 8 in the terminal, but when i try and select python linter on vs code in the command palette i get the following error: "Command 'Python: Select Linter' resulted in an error (command 'python.setLinter' not found)". I'm on a mac, version 11.5.2.

I have seen other solutions for this problem for windows on stack but not sure how to proceed on mac, please advise

Answer (score -2):

There are many possibilities. You can try the following methods:

1. Reinstall Python extension or use Pre-release version.
2. Start VsCode as administrator.
3. Try to delete the`.vscode` folder in the project.

Comment: "file not found" => "run your text editor as administrator" is terrible advice

Comment: @anthonysottile Is it possible that this is an editor setting rather than a file?